# Is there any evidence that less thinking about the future improves mental health?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, stress

Recently I heard a lecture about the philosophy of minimalism and the rethor argued that it's [better](https://nautilusmode.com/2016/01/05/keeping-a-minimalist-planner-for-2016/) not to [think](http://www.theminimalists.com/21days/) much about what you're going to do in the near future for example in the form of writing
less information in your calendar/planner.

What has the research found about how intensive thinking about the near future affects our mental health?

Comment: I have just been looking at the links you provided and they seem to contradict what you are asking about - especially the link under *think*. You talked about a lecture on writing less in your calendar or planner, yet the link under *better* introduces you to minimalist planners etc. and the other link is all about thinking and planning how you are going to change to living a minimalist life. I am confused.

Comment: Writing less doesn't mean contemplate less.